# не работает широковещательный сокет на разных хостах на с++

Tags: c++, сокет

Делаю широковещательный сокет на с++. на клиенте установила setsockopt и в адресе прописала INADDR_BROADCAST. проблема в том, что когда я включаю клиент и сервер на одном компьютере, то всё работает, а когда сервер и клиент располагаются на разных то до сервера ничего не доходит.Пробовали отключать антивирусники, пробовали отключать брандмауэр, соединяться по витой паре, ничего не помогло. Как можно решить эту проблему?
Вот клиент.

```
 // ClientBr.cpp: определяет точку входа для консольного приложения.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Winsock2.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include"GetErrorMsgText.h"
#pragma comment(lib,"WS2_32.lib") // экспорт  WS2_32.dll
using namespace std;


bool GetServer(SOCKET cC,char *call, short port, sockaddr* from,  unsigned int flen, int *lto, in_addr addr)
{
    try
    {

    int  lobuf = 0;  
    char ibuf[100000];                  //буфер ввода  
        int  lb = 0;
        port=htons(2000);
    if ((lobuf = sendto(cC,call,strlen(call)+1,NULL,
            from, flen)) == SOCKET_ERROR)   
            throw  SetErrorMsgText("recv:");
    cout<<"Отправлено сообщение "<<call<<endl;
    cout<<"Порт сервера "<<htons(port)<<" IP "<<inet_ntoa(addr)<<endl;
    if ((lb = recvfrom(cC,ibuf, sizeof(ibuf), NULL,
            from, lto))   ==  SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
            throw  SetErrorMsgText("recv error");
            return false;
    }
    else 
    {
        cout<<"Позывной сервера:"<<endl;
        cout<<ibuf<<endl;



        cout<<"Получено "<<lb<<" bit "<<endl;
    return true;
    }
    }
    catch(string errorMsgText){
        cout <<endl;

        ErrorMsgText(WSAGetLastError());
        cout <<"Код ошибки: "<<WSAGetLastError()<<endl; // hm hm
    }
}



int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsaData;

    system("chcp 1251");

    try 
    {
        if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0), &wsaData) != 0)
            throw  SetErrorMsgText("Startup error");
        SOCKET cC;
        if ((cC = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, NULL))== INVALID_SOCKET) 
            throw  SetErrorMsgText("socket error");
        int optval = 1;
        if (setsockopt(cC,SOL_SOCKET,SO_BROADCAST,
               (char*)&optval,sizeof(optval)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
          throw  SetErrorMsgText("opt:");




        SOCKADDR_IN serv;                     // параметры  сокета cC
        serv.sin_family  = AF_INET;           // используется IP-адресация  
        serv.sin_port = htons(2000);          // порт 2000
        serv.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_BROADCAST ;     // любой собственный IP-адрес inet_addr("127.0.0.1")

        char obuf[100000];   //буфер вывода
        int  lobuf = 0;                    //количество отправленных  
        int  lb = 0;
        int lc = sizeof(serv);

        cout<<"Введите сообщение серверу"<<endl;
        cin>>obuf;

        GetServer(cC,obuf,2000,(sockaddr*)&serv, sizeof(serv), &lc,serv.sin_addr);
        //cout<<"Ip-адрес сервера: "<<inet_ntoa(serv.sin_addr)<<" порт: "<<htons(serv.sin_port)<<endl;

        int time=clock();
        cout<<"Время обмена сообщениями "<<time<<endl;


        if (closesocket(cC)== SOCKET_ERROR)
            throw  SetErrorMsgText("closesocket error");

        if (WSACleanup()== SOCKET_ERROR)         
            throw  SetErrorMsgText("Cleanup error");

    }
    catch (string errorMsgText) // hm hm hm
    {
        cout <<endl;

        ErrorMsgText(WSAGetLastError());
        cout <<"Код ошибки: "<<WSAGetLastError()<<endl; // hm hm
    }
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Вот сервер:

```
    // ServerT.cpp: определяет точку входа для консольного приложения.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Winsock2.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include"GetErrorMsgText.h"
#include "windows.h"
#pragma warning (disable: 4996) 
#pragma comment(lib,"WS2_32.lib") // экспорт  WS2_32.dll
using namespace std;

bool GetRequestFromClient(SOCKET Ss, char name[100000], short port,sockaddr* from, int * flen,in_addr addr)
{
    try{

        char message[100000];
        if ((recvfrom(Ss,message , sizeof(message), NULL,
                from, flen))   ==  SOCKET_ERROR)
    { 
        throw  SetErrorMsgText("recv");
        return false;
    }
    else 
    {
        if (*message==*name)
        {    

        cout<<"Правильный позывной"<<endl;
        cout<<"Порт клиента "<<htons(port)<<" IP "<<inet_ntoa(addr)<<endl;
        return true;
        }
        else
        {
        cout<<"Неправильный позывной"<<endl;
        GetRequestFromClient(Ss,name,port,from, flen,addr);
        }
    }
    }
    catch (string errorMsgText) 
    {
        cout <<endl;    

        ErrorMsgText(WSAGetLastError());
        cout <<"WSAGetLastError: "<<WSAGetLastError()<<endl; 
    }
}   

bool PutAnswerToClient(SOCKET sS,char* name  ,   unsigned int lto, sockaddr* to)
{
    try{

        if ((sendto(sS,name,strlen(name)+1,NULL,to, lto)) == SOCKET_ERROR)   
                throw  SetErrorMsgText("send error");
    else cout <<"Позывной отправлен клиенту "<<endl;
    return true;
    }
    catch (string errorMsgText) 
    {
        cout <<endl;

        ErrorMsgText(WSAGetLastError());
        cout <<"WSAGetLastError: "<<WSAGetLastError()<<endl; 
    }
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    system("chcp 1251");
        char name[100000]="hi";
    SOCKET sS;


    try 
    {
        if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0), &wsaData) != 0)
            throw  SetErrorMsgText("Startup error");


        if((sS = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, NULL))== INVALID_SOCKET) 
            throw  SetErrorMsgText("socket error"); 

        SOCKADDR_IN serv;                     // параметры  сокета sS
        serv.sin_family  = AF_INET;           // используется IP-адресация  
        serv.sin_port = htons(2000);          // порт 2000
        serv.sin_addr.s_addr =  INADDR_ANY;   // любой собственный IP-адрес 

        if (bind(sS,(LPSOCKADDR)&serv, sizeof(serv))== SOCKET_ERROR)
            throw  SetErrorMsgText("bind error");

        SOCKADDR_IN clnt;               // параметры  сокета клиента
        memset(&clnt,0,sizeof(clnt));   // обнулить память
        int lc = sizeof(clnt);

        int ls=sizeof(serv);

        while (true)
        {   
            GetRequestFromClient(sS, name,htons(2000),(sockaddr*)&clnt,&lc,clnt.sin_addr);
            //cout<<"Ip-адрес клиента: "<<inet_ntoa(clnt.sin_addr)<<" порт: "<<htons(clnt.sin_port)<<endl;
            cout<<endl;
            PutAnswerToClient(sS,name, sizeof(serv),(sockaddr*)&clnt);
        }
        if (closesocket(sS)== SOCKET_ERROR)
            throw  SetErrorMsgText("closesocket error");

        if (WSACleanup()== SOCKET_ERROR)         
            throw  SetErrorMsgText("Cleanup error");

    }
    catch (string errorMsgText) 
    {
        cout <<endl;

        ErrorMsgText(WSAGetLastError());
        cout <<"WSAGetLastError: "<<WSAGetLastError()<<endl; 
    }
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А Wireshark'ом смотрели?

Comment: Это лабораторная работа в университете

Comment: Прикол в том, что UDP-сокет работает на различных хостах на ура, как только я переделала его под broadcast, то всё  - только на одном хосте

Comment: Пожалуйста, если в следующий раз кто-то из участников будет позволять себе неуместные замечания - поставьте на них флаг тревоги для модераторов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была лишь в том, что не был отключен VirtualBox Host-Only Network, сетевое подключение Bluetooth и подключение по локальной сети. Когда я это всё отключила широковещательный сокет заработал на разных хостах.
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]